# What does the symbol $f^*\langle v,w\rangle _p$ mean in DoCarmo's Differential Geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm preparing the differential geometric exam, but I don't have the textbook on hand. My teacher's lecture note left a symbol $f^*\langle v,w\rangle _p$ without further explanation, so I don't know what it means. I think it is hard for me to google something especially in the topic of differential geometry--many people have their own definitions and terminologies. So I decide to ask here. Let me first state a definition in our teacher's lecture notes: (the appointed textbook is doCarmo's)

> If $S_1,S_2$ are surfaces, a smooth map $f:S_1\rightarrow S_2$ is called local isometry if it takes any curve in $S_1$ to a curve of the same length in $S_2$.

Next, the note said that,

> If $f:S_1\rightarrow S_2$ is differentiable, $p\in S_1$ and $v,w\in T_p(S_1)$, then $f^*\langle v,w\rangle _p=\langle df_p(v),df_p(w)\rangle_{f(p)}$, where $f^*\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_p$ is a symmetric bilinear form on $T_pS$.

So my question is, what is the symbol $f^*\langle v,w\rangle_p$ here? What does it mean? Is $f^*$ related to the original function $f$?

Comment: @MichaelHardy OK now I've edited.

Comment: To me it looks like that sentence is the *definition* of the function $f^*\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_p$, evidently a function from $T_p(S_1)\times T_p(S_1)$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Rahul. So that's how it is! I understand soon after your explanation.

Comment: "(easy question)" If this was easy to you you would not ask the question, right?

Comment: @Did I'm sure it is easy to others, it is just a matter of definition and terminology.

Answer (score 4):

This is known as the [*pullback metric*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#The_pullback_metric). The notation $(f^* g)(v,w) = g(Df(v),Df(w))$ is standard, so this is a fairly natural adaptation to the $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ notation for the metric.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is just a notation for $\langle df_p(v), df_p(w) \rangle$, because it is also used in *Elementary Differential Geometry* by Andrew Pressley. Quoting (page $127$):

> Let $f:S_1 \to S_2$ be a smooth map and let $p \in S_1$. For $v,w \in T_pS_1$, define:
>
> $$f^*\langle v,w\rangle_p = \langle D_pf(v),D_pf(w) \rangle_{f(p)}$$